# How to use document library title instead of document metadata title for search results?

Tags: search

We are running a SharePoint 2010 installation that, among other things, hosts internal documents.  These documents are stored via a Document Library and are served out on individual pages via Content Query Webparts.  The links for these documents are the titles as dictated by the document library (NOT the metadata title of the document itself).  In addition to this, we have setup a basic search center.  The problem we are running into is that when users search for documents, the results display the metadata title of the document instead of its document library title resulting in links that don't match between pages.

My question is this:  How can we have the search results display the document title as dictated by the document library?  Or, alternatively, is there an easy way to copy the document library title to the metadata document title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI I had the same exact issue, with both 2003 and 2007 documents, and the fix in this blog post did the trick:

http://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/incorrect-search-result-title-for-word-2007-documents-in-sharepoint-2010-search/

Comment: That's brilliant.  I wish we would have known that workaround before we implemented.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you need to modify the XSLT used to display the search results.  If you edit the search results page in your search centre you will see a web part called Search Core Results.  This is the web part responsible for rendering the search results via XSLT.

There are plenty of articles out there on how to do this, just google 'Customizing SharePoint 2010 Search Results'

Comment: Is there already a fetched property for the document list titles?  Or will I have to define something somewhere for it?  And if so, how?